# Get string from EditText without nullable error

Tags: java, android, nullable

I have found out that the problem is, that the `EditText` returns a `NullPointerException` ([Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException)). Now I've searched on Google for hours for solutions and found some, but they are not working right for me. Is someone able to edit mine code so that i correctly get the value from the `Edittext` as a string. Here is mine code:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- Page Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PageTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/test_title"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<!-- Input 1 -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text=""
    android:hint="@string/hint_input"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/translation1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PageTitle"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

<!-- Translation 1 -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/translation1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/test"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/input1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PageTitle"/>

<!--Check button-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="Check"
    android:text="@string/check_btn"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/translation1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/input1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PageTitle" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java**

```
package com.bnf.overhooring;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

String right = getString(R.string.right);
String wrong = getString(R.string.wrong);
String translation1 = getString(R.string.translation1);

EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
String string1 = input1.getText().toString();

public void Check(View view) {
    if (string1.equals(translation1)) input1.setText(right);
    else input1.setText(wrong);
 }
}
```

**stack trace**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.bnf.overhooring, PID: 30985
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bnf.overhooring/com.bnf.overhooring.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2849)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)
                  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:127)
                  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:121)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
                  at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:476)
                  at com.bnf.overhooring.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: don't access your views before setcontentview and findviewbyid , seems like the issue

Comment: Thanks for the quick respons.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Yes coming up !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, stripped down, looks like this:

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>     String right = getString(R.string.right);
>     String wrong = getString(R.string.wrong);
>     String translation1 = getString(R.string.translation1);
> }
> ```

Exactly what happens when you call `getString()` is somewhat complicated, but the important thing to understand is that it requires a `Resources` object. This `Resources` object isn't "ready" immediately when your activity instance is being constructed, and that's when you're trying to call `getString()`.

In general, wait until `super.onCreate()` has been called before trying to access the resources framework; this includes calling `getString()`.

You can fix it by changing your code to look like this instead:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String right;
    private String wrong;
    private String translation1;
    private EditText input1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.right = getString(R.string.right);
        this.wrong = getString(R.string.wrong);
        this.translation1 = getString(R.string.translation1);
        this.input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
    }

    public void Check(View view) {
        String string1 = input1.getText().toString();

        if (string1.equals(translation1)) {
            input1.setText(right);
        }
        else {
            input1.setText(wrong);
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing we've done here is to move the assignment of `right`, `wrong`, `translation1`, and `input1` into our `onCreate()` method. We also make sure that the `getString()` calls happen after `super.onCreate()` and that the `findViewById()` call happens after `setContentView()`. The order is very important.

Finally, there's no reason to assign a value to `string1` until your `Check()` method is actually called. That way we make sure we're working with the most up-to-date value from our `EditText`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, this code works fine and solves the problem perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the views before onCreate happens in the lifecycle. It's when the Android initializate all the views and you can access it.

This works fine for me

```
package com.example.casti.myapplication;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String right = "right";
    String wrong = "wrong";
    String translation1 = "translation1";

    EditText input1;
    String string1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        input1 = findViewById(R.id.input1);
        string1 = input1.getText().toString();
    }

    public void Check(View view) {
        if (string1.equals(translation1)) input1.setText(right);
        else input1.setText(wrong);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reaction, This does not resolve the error I'm currently having.(See the updated question). Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ok, but i'll recommend it that you move your getText like I said before. This will help you not shoot in your own foot in the future. Can you update your question with more code? This is not enough to understand  the problem

Comment: Ah, ok i will definitely change mine code thx, I'll upload mine xml and java in a few minutes.

Comment: I updated my answer. Your code was broking, with the changes I made it, it works fine